# Completing the explicit $\lim\limits_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}(r,c)$/ inverse $\int_0^x\frac{t^{r-1}}{1-t}dt,r\in\Bbb Q$ series expansion

Tags: convergence-divergence, special-functions, inverse-function, beta-function, lagrange-inversion

**Introduction:**

Using:

> [Elementary closed form of $\exp\left(b\int_0^x \frac{t^{a-1}}{1-t^b}dt\right);a,b\in\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540152/elementary-closed-form-of-exp-leftb-int-0x-fracta-11-tbdt-righta/4540998#4540998)

and [**inverse beta regularized**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized), which gives [quantiles](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f+distribution+quantile) meaning its parameters are nonzero, there is limit, [**incomplete beta function $\text B_x(u,v)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=beta%28x%2Cu%2Cv%29) function, and [Lerch Phi $\Phi(z,s,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Lerch+transcendent) $$f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{t^{a-1+\frac pq}}{1-t}dt=x^{a+\frac pq}\Phi\left(x,1,a+\frac pq\right)=\text B_x\left(a+\frac pq,0\right)=-\sum_{n=0}^{q-1}e^{-\frac{2\pi i n p}q}\ln\left(1-\sqrt[q]xe^{\frac{2\pi i n}q}\right)-\sum_{n=0}^{a-1}\frac{x^{n+\frac pq}}{n+\frac pq}\tag1$$$$\implies f^{-1}(x)=\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}(x,c);a,p,q\in\Bbb N,p<q,0\le x\le 1\tag2$$ The following derivations use the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), [**multinomial $\binom n{n_1,\dots,n_k}$**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Multinomial/) [**expansion**](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Multinomial/31/01/), [generalized product rule](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Multinomial/31/02/), and [Kronecker delta $\delta$](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/KroneckerDelta2/).

**$a+\frac pq$ case?:**

This method fails as shown by the $p=1,a=q=2$ case. Using Lagrange inversion: $$\sqrt{\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{-c\ln(x)}\left(\frac52,0\right)}=1+\sum_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x-1}{e^{-\text B_{x^2}\left(\frac52,0\right)}}\right)^n=1+\sum_{n=1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(-e^{-\frac23nx^3}e^{-2nx}(x+1)^n\right)$$ Now use the generalized product rule: $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(-e^{-\frac23nx^3}e^{-2nx}(x+1)^n\right)=\lim_{x\to1}(-1)^n\sum_{p=0}^{n-1}\sum_{q=1}^{n-1}\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}\delta_{p+q+r,n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{p!q!r!}\frac{d^p}{dx^p}(x-1)^n\frac{d^q}{dx^q}e^{-2nx}\frac{d^r}{dx^r}e^{-\frac23 n x^3}$$ using the [hypergeometric function $_p\text F_q$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) the problem occurs here: $$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{\delta_{p+q+r,n-1}}{r!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^r}{dx^r}e^{-\frac23nx^3}\mathop=^?\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{\delta_{p+q+r,n-1}}{r!}\sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-\frac23n\right)^t (3t)!}{t!(3t-r)!}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{\delta_{p+q+r,n-1}\,_3\text F_3(…)}{(-r)!r!}=\frac{\delta_{p+q,n-1}}{e^{\frac23n}}+0+0+\dots$$ Therefore, the series probably converges to the wrong function. What is the simplest explicit series expansion for $(2)$ or the inverse of $(1)$?

**$a=0$ case:**

$$\sqrt[q]{\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{-c\ln(x)}\left(\frac pq,c\right)}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\left(\frac{x-1}{e^{-\text B_{x^q}\left(\frac pq,0\right)}}\right)^n\right)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{q-1}\left(1-(-1)^\frac{2k}qx\right)^{-n(-1)^\frac{2kp}q}$$ Applying the generalized product rule, $\displaystyle\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_j}=\sum_{n_1}\dots\sum_{n_j}$, and [**factorial power $u^{(v)}$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorialPower.html) $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{q-1}\left(1-(-1)^\frac{2k}qx\right)^{-n(-1)^\frac{2kp}q}=\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_{q-1}=0}^{n-1}\delta_{n-1,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{q-1}n_k}\binom n{n_1,\dots,n_{q-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{q-1}\left(\frac{d^{n_k}}{dx^{n_k}} \left(1-(-1)^\frac{2k}qx\right)^{-n(-1)^\frac{2kp}q}\right)_{x=1}=\sum_{n_1,\dots n_{q-1}=0}^{n-1} \delta_{n-1,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{q-1}n_k} n!\prod_{k=1}^{q-1} \frac{(-1)^ \frac{2kn_ k}q}{n_ k!}\left(-n(-1)^{- \frac{2kp}q}\right)^{(n_k)}\left(1-(-1)^\frac{2k}q\right)^{-n(-1)^{-\frac{2kp}q}-n_k}$$ Therefore we have a multidimensional series expansion, which are hard to evaluate one by one because of Kronecker delta: $$\boxed{\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}\left(\frac pq,c\right)=\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-e^{-x})^n}n\sum_{n_1=0}^{n-1}\dots\sum_{n_{q-1}}^{n-1}\delta_{n-1,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{q-1}n_k} \prod_{k=1}^{q-1} \frac{(-1)^ \frac{2kn_ k}q}{n_ k!}\left(-n(-1)^{- \frac{2kp}q}\right)^{(n_k)}\left(1-(-1)^\frac{2k}q\right)^{-n(-1)^{-\frac{2kp}q}-n_k}\right)^q}$$ Interestingly, the series diverges for $\frac pq=\frac14$, but the Lagrange inversion coefficients match for: $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\left(\frac{x-1}{e^{-\text B_{x^4}\left(\frac 34,0\right)}}\right)^n\right)=\left\{\vphantom{e^\frac12}\right.-2e^{-\frac\pi 2}$,[$-4e^{-\pi}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B%28-I%29%5Er+I%5Em+%281+-+I%29%5E%28-2+I-r%29+%281+%2B+I%29%5E%282+I-m%29+2%5E%282+-+k%29+FactorialPower%5B-2+I%2C+r%5D+FactorialPower%5B2+I%2C+m%5DFactorialPower%5B2%2Ck%5DKroneckerDelta%5B1%2Ck%2Bm%2Br%5D%28%28k%2Bm%2Br%29%21%29%2F%28k%21m%21r%21%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Br%2C0%2C1%7D%5D), [$-36e^{-\frac{3\pi}2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B%28k%2Bm%2Br%29%21%2F%28k%21m%21r%21%29kroneckerdelta%282%2Ck%2Bm%2Br%29%28-I%29%5Er+I%5Em%281-I%29%5E%28-3+I-r%29+%281+%2B+I%29%5E%283+I+-+m%292%5E%283+-+k%29FactorialPower%5B-3+I%2C+r%5DFactorialPower%5B3+I%2C+m%5DFactorialPower%5B3%2C+k%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C2%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C2%7D%5D%2C%7Br%2C0%2C2%7D%5D), [$-464e^{-2\pi}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B%28k%2Bm%2Br%29%21%2F%28k%21m%21r%21%29kroneckerdelta%283%2Ck%2Bm%2Br%29+%28-I%29%5Er+I%5Em+%281+-+I%29%5E%28-4+I-r%29%281%2BI%29%5E%284+I+-+m%29+2%5E%284+-+k%29FactorialPower%5B-4+I%2C+r%5DFactorialPower%5B4+I%2C+m%5DFactorialPower%5B4%2C+k%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C3%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C3%7D%5D%2C%7Br%2C0%2C3%7D%5D), $\dots\left.\vphantom{e^\frac12}\right\}$

**$p=0$ case:**

$$\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{-c\ln(x)}(a,c)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\left(\frac{x-1}{e^{-\text B_x(a,0)}}\right)^n\right)= 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{-n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{x^k}k}$$ Now expand the derivative argument as a sum with the multinomial expansion: $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}e^{-n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{x^k}k}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-n)^m}{m!}\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\frac{x^k}k\right)^m= \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-n)^m}{m!}\sum_{m_1,\dots,m_{a-1}=0}^m\delta_{m,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}m_k}\binom m{m_1,\dots,m_{a-1}} \lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\prod_{k=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{x^k}k\right)^{n_k}= \sum_{m=0}^\infty(-n)^m\sum_{m_1,\dots,m_{a-1}=0}^m\delta_{m,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}m_k}\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}x^{kn_k}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}m_k!k^{m_k}}$$ Evaluating the derivatives using factorial power, combining both steps, and algebra presents: $$\boxed{\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}(a,c)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(-e^{-x}\right)^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{m_1=0}^m\dots\sum_{m_{a-1}=0}^m\frac{\delta_{m,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}m_k}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}km_k\right)^{(n-1)}(-n)^m}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{a-1}m_k!k^{m_k}}}$$ which match these Lagrange inversion coefficients: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\left(\frac{x-1}{e^{-\text B_x(3,0)}}\right)^n\right)=\left\{\vphantom{e^\frac122}\right.$[$-e^{-\frac32}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%283%2F2%29*sum%5B%28-1%29%5E1%28-1%29%5Em+sum%5Bsum%5Bkroneckerdelta%28m%2Ck%2Br%291%2F%28k%21+r%21%29+2%5E%28-r%29+factorialpower%28%282+r+%2B+k%29%2C+-1+%2B+1%29%2C%7Br%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D),[$4e^{-3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4e%5E-3%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E2%28-2%29%5Em+sum%5Bsum%5Bkroneckerdelta%28m%2Ck%2Br%291%2F%28k%21+r%21%29+2%5E%28-r%29+factorialpower%28%282+r+%2B+k%29%2C+-1+%2B+2%29%2C%7Br%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D),[$33e^{-\frac92}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=33e%5E%28-9%2F2%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E3%28-3%29%5Em+sum%5Bsum%5Bkroneckerdelta%28m%2Ck%2Br%291%2F%28k%21+r%21%29+2%5E%28-r%29+factorialpower%28%282+r+%2B+k%29%2C+-1+%2B+3%29%2C%7Br%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C20%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C20%7D%5D),[$416e^{-6}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=416e%5E%28-6%29%2Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5E4%28-4%29%5Em+sum%5Bsum%5Bkroneckerdelta%28m%2Ck%2Br%291%2F%28k%21+r%21%29+2%5E%28-r%29+factorialpower%28%282+r+%2B+k%29%2C+-1+%2B+4%29%2C%7Br%2C0%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C100%7D%5D)$\left.\vphantom{e^\frac12},\dots\right\}$

**Question:**

The $a=0$ and $p=0$ cases are boxed and partly tested. What is the most concise explicit series expansion for $(2)$ or the inverse of $(1)$? Optionally, it should be testable in WolframAlpha or a similar software.

Comment: If [these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2BSum%5B%28-e%5E%28-1%2F4%29%29%5En%2Fn%21+Sum%5Bi%5Ek+2%5E%28k+%2B+1%29+%281+-+i%29%5E%28-i+n%29+%281+%2B+i%29%5E%28-k+%2B+i+n%29*+binomial%28n-1%2Ck%29*+factorialpower%28%28i+n%29%2C+k%29+factorialpower%28n%2C+-k%2Bn-1%29+2F1%28-k%2C+i+n%2C+-k+%2B+i+n+%2B+1%2C+-i%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C25-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C25%7D%5D%29%5E4) [links](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversebetaregularized%280.0001*1%2F4%2C3%2F4%2C0.0001%29) show:

Comment: $$\lim_{c\to0}\text I^{-1}_{cx}\left(\frac34,0\right)=\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-e^{-x})^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}m i^m 2^{m+1}(1-i)^{-in}(1+i)^{in-m}(in)^{(m)}n^{(n-m-1)}\,_2\text F_1(-m,in;in-m+1;-i)\right)^4$$ then what could an expansion for $(2)$ look like?

Comment: We get a series for $\text I^{-1}_x(1-r,r),r\in\Bbb Q$ and there is a form for it without $\delta_{n,k}$. Also, $\text I^{-1}_x\left(n+\frac12,m+\frac12\right)$ has a Fourier series with [this generalized Bessel function](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82678941.pdf) expressible as a sum of Bessel functions

Comment: There should be a sum of a lauricella function closed form for the $a=0$ part using [this identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1243)